# glsl "uniform grid" bucketing

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, glsl, webgl, gpu

I am attempting to do a uniform grid bucketing:
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/A-2D-uniform-grid-example-with-grid-cell-and-particle-ids_fig3_325579657

https://jsfiddle.net/mikoval/0147xwfq/12/
Works on one computer, doesn't on other. Bucket values will print in console.

---

And everything works fine on one of my computers, but when I test on another computer, I am getting VERY different results. The algorithm I am using works as follows:

Generate two render targets. Use one as the input and one as the output. At the start of each frame clear them both.

Render all of the particles into the framebuffer based off of a position texture. Instead of rendering a color, I render the index of the particle. I use the output of this process to pass into the next render. During each render there is a check to see if the particle has already been rendered, and if it is, it is ignored. This way I can have up to 4 different particles in the same grid location (each one would be stored in an RGBA channel as a single index).

The following are my shaders:

```
this.bucketVertex = `#version 300 es
    precision highp float;
    in ivec2 position;
    flat out ivec2 id;
    out vec2 pv;
    uniform vec2 res;
    uniform sampler2D image;
    uniform sampler2D current;
    void main() {
        gl_PointSize = 1.0;
        id = position;

        float aspect = res.y / res.x;
        vec2 pos = texelFetch(image, position, 0).xy;

        pos.x *= aspect;


        float gSize = float(textureSize(image, 0).x);
        float val = float(id.x + id.y * int(gSize) + 1);

        vec2 b = floor(pos * gSize)/gSize + 0.5/gSize;

        pv = (b + 1.0)/2.0;


        vec4 c = texture(current, pv.xy);

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            if(c[i] == val) {
                b = vec2(1000.0, 1000.0);
            }
        }





        gl_Position = vec4(b, 0, 1);
    }
    `;

this.bucketFragment = `#version 300 es
    precision highp float;
    flat in ivec2 id;
    in vec2 pv;
    out vec4 outColor;
    uniform sampler2D current;
    uniform sampler2D image;

    void main() {
        vec2 p = pv;
        vec4 c = texture(current, p.xy);

        int size = textureSize(image, 0).x;
        int val = id.x + id.y * size + 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            if(c[i] == 0.0){
                c[i] = float(val);
                break;
            }
        }




        outColor = c;
    }
    `;
```

and my bucket render loop looks like the following:

```
    /* clear previous run */
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.bucketTarget2.fb);
    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);


    gl.disable(gl.BLEND);



    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.bucketTarget.fb);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, this.bucketTarget.fb.width, this.bucketTarget.fb.height);

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.useProgram(this.bucketObj.program);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, state.texture);

    gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
    gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.bucketTarget2.texture);



    gl.uniform1i(this.bucketObj.uniformImage, 0);
    gl.uniform1i(this.bucketObj.uniformImage2, 1);

    gl.bindVertexArray(this.bucketVao);

    gl.uniform2f(this.bucketObj.uniformRes, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);


    for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, this.size * this.size);

        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, state.texture);
        gl.uniform1i(this.bucketObj.uniformImage, 0);


        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE1);
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.bucketTarget2.texture);
        gl.uniform1i(this.bucketObj.uniformImage2, 1);

        gl.copyTexImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, 0, 0, this.bucketTarget2.fb.width, this.bucketTarget2.fb.height, 0);
    }
```

As mentioned, this works completely fine on one computer, where a sample output texture could look like the following (yes it is a float texture):

```
[
    5, 0, 0, 0,
    3, 2, 0, 0,
    4, 1, 6, 0,
    7, 8, 0, 0
    ...
]
```

However, on the other computer I am getting the following:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0,
 1, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0,
 1, 1, 1, 4,
 1, 1, 1, 3,
 0, 0, 0, 0,
 1, 1, 1, 2,
 0, 0, 0, 0,
 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

For whatever reason, every time there is a particle that isn't a 1, the texture fills up with 1s and then just displays one value in the last channel.

If I only do `(for i = 0; i < 2; i++)`, then the texture looks like

[
  1, 4, 0, 0,
  1, 0, 0, 0,
  1, 3, 0, 0,
   ....
]

I have no idea where these 1s would be coming from based off the shader code though. I can try to make a fiddle the demonstrate later if helpful.

EDIT: Updated with gman's comment.

LINK TO DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/mikoval/0147xwfq/12/

Comment: In your shader `DIMENSION` is not defined but in any case looking up individual pixels you need to either use integer values and `texelFetch` or you need to add 1/2 a pixel as in `texture(tex, (xyPixelOffset + .5) / textureDimensions)`. Note that you can look up texture dimensions with `textureSize`. I'd just use `texelFetch` instead of `texture` but just remember it takes integer texel coordinates, not normalized texture coordinates. No idea if that's your issue but if you're not adding .5 to normalized texture coordinates than you're computing the edges between texels which is problematic

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the advice. I didn't know about texelFetch, but did notice I was having some problems with the texture lookups (The second texture lookup was doing it).  I think texelFetch is a lot more intuitive with what it will return though, so will use that from now on. Unfortunately it didn't fix the problem I am having, but definitely fixes other problems.

Comment: I would suggest where it makes sense passing in `int` or `ivec` or `uvec` values where you're actually working with integers rather than float values you're casting to integers, at least in my experience GPUs can end up rounding down here or there and getting the wrong value. [Here's an example](https://github.com/greggman/vertexshaderart/issues/6#issuecomment-319936627). In other words, make `position` an `ivec2` or `uvec2` and use `gl.vertexAttribIPointer` and fill your buffer with ints or unsigned ints.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will make the change. I have had a lot of problems with precision in the past, this will definitely help

Comment: Turns out the problem was unrelated to the shaders. I was using glCopyTexImage2D on floating point textures, and my laptop allowed me to copy them successfully, while my desktop was clamping the values > 1 to 1. glCopyTexImage2D doesn't officially support floating point textures, and I just got lucky that it was working.

Comment: I'm guessing (but not sure) that `copyTexImage2D` will work if you check for and enable `EXT_color_buffer_float`.  Of course if your laptop doesn't support that extension then it won't work but `copyTexImage2D` should be consistent across webgl2 implementations. If it is not then either you enabled `EXT_color_buffer_float` on one but not the other (maybe you didn't check for success?) or there's a bug in your browser. Can you [run this test](http://jsfiddle.net/greggman/jbn1v7he/) on your desktop and laptop and tell me the results and if one fails a pastebin of your about:gpu page?

Comment: The test ran fine on both, I already have the extensions enabled. So not sure what is going on with the copy. I already was doing gl.getExtension("OES_texture_float_linear") , gl.getExtension("EXT_color_buffer_float") and both ran fine.